# Manipulation of data in multiple worksheets - VBA

Tags: vba

I'm new programmer in VBA and I need to compare values ​​in different worksheets to make a decision.

I have a template of a test in one of the worksheets, and the other worksheets have the answers of each student. In practice, in cell A1 of Sheet1 is the correct answer. Now I have to go through all the sheets and check if in cell A1 of each answer is correct.

My code follows:

```
Function Answer(Var As Range) As Long

   For Each Plan In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       Plan.Activate
       If Plan.Range(Var).Value = 1 Then 'Line 4
          Answer = Answer + 1
       End If
   Next Plan

End Function
```

In line 4 I try to get value of the current cell. But, it's return a #Value error.
Can anyone help me?

Thank's very much for any help!

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Sorry, that was too quick. This one should work:

```
Function Answer(Var As Range) As Long
   For Each Plan In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       If Plan.Range(Var.Address).Value = 1 Then 'Line 4
          Answer = Answer + 1
       End If
   Next Plan

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are passing the wrong parameter to the function. Since you want to check the range `A1` of each sheet I suggest the following modification:

```
Function Answer(rngAddress as String) As Long
   For Each Plan In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  
      If Plan.Range(rngAddress).Value = 1 Then  Answer = Answer + 1       
   Next Plan
End Function
'Usage:
Debug.Print Answer("A1")
```

**Tip:** You don't need to activate the worksheet in order to get the value from a cell